# GWT: DeveloperModeLogHandler vs SystemLogHandler

Tags: gwt, logging

In the GWT logging framework, is the difference between the DeveloperModeLogHandler, and the SystemLogHandler?  They seem to both do the same thing: log messages to stdout and stderr which show up in the development window.

Is there a reason to prefer one over the other?  Because currently my log messages are being duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the way you are using to log a message. If you are using method **GWT.log** then prefer DevelopmentModeLogHandler over SystemLogHandler.

Here a description of the handlers from [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html#Configuring_GWT_Logging).

**SystemLogHandler**

- Logs to stdout. These messages can only be seen in Development Mode — look for them in the DevMode window

**DevelopmentModeLogHandler**

- Logs by calling method **GWT.log**. These messages can only be seen in Development mode — look for them in the DevMode window

Comment: There seems to be no other client side logging in the application.  What's the benefit of GWT.log over stdout?  Especially when considering both loggers only show in development mode.